# itunes was unable to load data class information from sync services

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I recently installed the beta version of xCode, iTunes and the iOS software. I am now getting the above warning in iTunes. xCode doesn't recognize that a phone is connected so I cannot run test apps on my phone.

Any ideas on how to fix this or what went wrong?

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the same message from iTunes 11.0 having installed XCode 4.6DP3. Except that Xcode sees my devices OK; if I dismiss the alert things seem to work as usual.

Comment: things do work as usual, except that you cannot backup/restore iphones through iTunes.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the following framework:

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Mobiledevice.framework

.. empty trash, reinstall iTunes 11.

Comment: Seems like this works, let's see, how things will be in a couple of days.